# How to use Typescript typing for a dynamically generated class?

Tags: javascript, typescript, import

I am implementing a class like the following:

```js
import * as User from './user';

export class Database {
  constructor() {
    for (const method in User) {
      this[method] = User[method];
    }
  }
}
```

Where the ./user file contains:

```js
export async function findById(id: number): Promise<User | null> {
  return //
}

export async function findByName(name: string): Promise<User | null> {
  return //
}
```

I can now use the Database class to perform operations, however there are no TypeScript hints since these are lost by dynamically reassigning the methods. I also have to include a @ts-nocheck in the Database file as I am otherwise getting the error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof import
```

Implementing a predefined interface also will not work due to it not registering the dynamic types (which is logical as these are loaded in at runtime). How do I implement a dynamic interface for this?

Big thanks

Comment: You could do a simple cast when you create the instance,  instead of `const db = new Database()`  do -> `const db = new Database() as typeof User`,  if you call this a lot, a simple wrapped function maybe called `newDbInstance()` that has this on..  If your also wanting to expose other functions already on `Database` your could then do -> `const x = new Database() as (typeof UserProcs & Database);`

Comment: Also something to note, the functions your adding to Database are been added to the Object instance, if you create multiple instance of Database, you might find adding to the prototype makes more sense.  If so you could just do -> `Object.assign(Database.prototype, UserProcs)`, also this would work for `this` , `Object.assign(this, UserProcs)`..

Comment: Wow thanks so much, I was thinking way too complicated. Also the object assign solves the Typescript error for me!

Answer (score 1):

With suggestions from Keith I changed it to:

```
import * as User from './user';

export const Database = class _Database {
  constructor() {
    Object.assign(this, User);
  }
} as { new (): typeof User };
```

This solved the TypeScript errors (yay)